# Perform page url routing based on slash delimited string

Tags: php, string, split, url-routing, delimited

I am working with the PHP explode function. This function is used to detect page URL.

In our website settings, the page URLs are:

1. /app/home/  *(Home page)*
2. /app/answers/list  *(Search list page)*
3. /app/answers/detail/a_id/309   *(Answer detail page)*
4. /app/answers/list/session/L3NpZC9WVmpBQWlxaw%3D%3D

Currently, I am using the explode function to split up the strings and store them in an array.

```
$currentLocation  =explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

Array ( [0] => [1] => app [2] => answers [3] => list [4] => session [5] => L3NpZC9WVmpBQWlxaw%3D%3D )
```

And then there are a lot of IF Else condition statement:

```
if ($currentLocation [2]=='home')
        {
            $this->data['pageURL']=$currentLocation [2]; //Home directory
        }
        else if($currentLocation [2]=='answers')
        {
            $this->data['pageURL']= $currentLocation [4];
        }
```

I am wondering whether there is a smart way to achieve this. Thank you. the /app/ part of URL is always fixed, the rest will change.

Cheers,
Qing

Comment: For a framework that does this sort of thing for you, look at [Zend Router](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-router/routing/) in the Zend Framework (now, in 2023, renamed to [laminas-router](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-router/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you've got a lot of if/else conditions like that, it would be more common to use a `switch` statement instead:

```
switch $currentLocation[2] {
    case 'home' : $this->data['pageURL']=$currentLocation[2]; break;
    case 'answers' : $this->data['pageURL']= $currentLocation[4]; break;
    default: $this->data['pageURL']= $currentLocation[4]; break;
}
```

It's neater than a bunch of `elseif` blocks, though it's not really much less code.

However in this case, I would say that you could probably achieve better results using a set of rewrite rules. You haven't specified it, but given the URLs you've described, it's possible that you're using mod_rewrite (or similar) in your server config to redirect the 'friendly' URL to the actual PHP page?

This is where I would suggest working. By using a set of mod_rewrite rules, you can have the PHP page receive normal `$_GET` variables.

mod_rewrite allows you to have URLs like `/app/answers/detail/a_id/309`, but the PHP program would receive it as if the user had typed in `app.php?page=answers&section=detail&a_id=309`. The rewrite rules are based on regular expressions, and you can make them quite complex, to allow for a variety of different URL formats.

If you implement that, you could probably throw away all the work you're doing in the program with `explode()` and then picking out the relevant bits of URL, and replace it all with about five lines in your server config (`.htaccess`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can not rewrite the URL structure. Since the vendor will not allow me to do that. Thanks Spudley.

Comment: @QLui: That's a real shame, because it would be a better way of doing it. Are you sure about that though? It's a pretty common thing to do these days, and a lot of common packages rely on mod_rewrite for their friendly URLs (Drupal, Wordpress, etc etc etc etc), so I would expect any half-decent hosting vendor to allow you to do it. So if your hosting vendor doesn't allow you to use mod_rewrite then I'd say you're with the wrong web host! Time to find someone better.

Comment: If this function runs every time page load, will it slow down the speed?

Comment: not if you write it properly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559/any-negative-impacts-when-using-mod-rewrite